# Not Able to Set Delegate of View Controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, delegates

I'm trying to push a view controller like so:

```
SampleViewControllerB *svcb = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewB"];
svcb.delegate = self;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:svcb animated:YES];
```

If I remove the  `svcb.delegate = self;` line, it compiles fine and works properly. However, if I try to add it in, it won't compile and gives the error

```
Property 'delegate' not found on object of type 'SampleViewControllerB *'
```

Does anybody know how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does `SampleViewControlerB` has a property `delegate`? I have to ask.

Comment: @Linuxios I assumed that UIViewControllers by default had a delegate property. Fixed now, my mistake! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your problem. You have to define your own `delegate` property in your class, and make calls to it yourself. Make sure to remember to make a delegate protocol too!

Comment: Yeah, I made the delegate protocol but forgot to actually define the `delegate` property in my .h file. I'll accept this answer once it'll let me... Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

`UIViewControler` does not have a delegate property, if you need to add a delegate to your `SampleViewControllerB` you will need to explicitly define it

Comment: Thanks, fixed now! I assumed that the `UIViewController` had a delegate property...

Answer (score 1):

make parentViewController variable in .h of SampleViewControllerB  say..

```
ParentViewController *parentObject ;
```

and make it proprty in same

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) ParentViewController *parentObject ;
```

and synthesize in .m of SampleViewControllerB  class

```
@synthesize parentObject ;
```

now use the code where you are pushing your controller

```
SampleViewControllerB *svcb = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewB"];
svcb.parentObject = self;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:svcb animated:YES];
```

hope this will help you

Comment: yes then make one reference of your parent in SampleViewControllerB class and make that property and synthesise it ... and then use it.. dond give it name delegate you can give anything .. and pass self in this.. and call your method just going to edit and use it see edited part...

Comment: Oh, I see... I already have something that is working, but thanks anyway. I'll try this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

For a Delegate property you need to add delegate methods in the protocol of the SampleViewControllerB class.